# How to add "single conditional steps" under build section using dsl script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm currently trying to develop a DSL script that can create a jenkins job with all required plugins and options.
I think I've almost completed all the section. But, I stuck up under build section where I've to include "conditional steps (single)" under Build.

Actually what I wanted is this
[image]

But, what I get is this

[image]

Here's the code that I used,

```
job('Sample_dev') {
    steps {
        conditionalSteps {
            condition {
                alwaysRun()
            }
        }
        maven {
            goals('install')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done few mistakes there:

- Using multi-step DSL for achieving single step.
- Pushed maven outside context like individual step.
- Wrong DSL for Maven Step declaration.

Try following

```
job('Sample_dev')
{
  steps{
      singleConditionalBuilder{
        condition{
            alwaysRun()
        }
        buildStep {
          maven{
            targets('install')
            name('')
            pom('')
            properties('')
            jvmOptions('')
            usePrivateRepository(false)
            settings {
                standard()
            }
            globalSettings {
                standard()
            }
            injectBuildVariables(false)
          }
        }
        runner {
          fail()
        }
      }
   }
}
```

The creator has deployed most on this url https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin. But I would suggest you install in you local instance and access it via `http://<your-jenkins-host>:<port> /plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html` as Job DSL support auto generation so there is bright chance that plugin not listed above still has DSL support.